# VBA Excel: Filling in cells based on user input

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create an infinite variable range of cells (horizontal). The idea I'm going for is if the user types in 30 (for example) into a textBox, the top row of cells is filled starting at 0 counting up to 29. I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways you could accomplish this, but they all would include the use of a loop. So I'd suggest starting by learning about loops. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)
    If N > Columns.Count Then
        N = Columns.Count
    End If

    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(1, i) = i - 1
    Next i
End Sub
```